# how to keep the class of matrix after ordering it in r

Tags: r, matrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R and matrix with 1 row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601692/r-and-matrix-with-1-row)

I have hundreds of matrix and in a for loop I am doing some alterations on them including ordering them. The problem is with matrices which have only one row. So when I order them their class would change from matrix to character like below:

```
> test1
 Gene ID  Gene Name Score(d) Fold Change q-value(%)
[1,] "g17035" "17035"   "-29.1"  "0.877"     "303.826" 
> class(test1)
[1] "matrix"
```

and when applying the order it becomes character class:

> test1 <- test1[order(test1[, 5]), ]

```
> test1
Gene ID   Gene Name    Score(d) Fold Change  q-value(%) 
"g17035"     "17035"     "-29.1"     "0.877"   "303.826" 
> class(test1)
[1] "character"
```

I even used the as.matrix but it changes the matrix in an unwanted order:

> test1 <-as.matrix( test1[order(test1[, 5]), ])

and then it would be like this:

```
> test1
    [,1]     
Gene ID     "g17035" 
Gene Name   "17035"  
Score(d)    "-29.1"  
Fold Change "0.877"  
q-value(%)  "303.826"
```

how can I fix it?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is to not reduce the dimension of the subset and the way to do it is with the `drop` argument to `[`. More info is available in `?"["`.

```
# Demo matrix
> a <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

# With reduction
> a[1,]
[1] 1 4 7
> class(a[1,])
[1] "integer"

# Without reduction
> a[1,,drop=FALSE]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
> class(a[1,,drop=FALSE])
[1] "matrix"
```

Comment: yes but the point is that if I do not use as.matrix in the next lines of the code I will get subscripts out of bound for example when I want to get the forth column of the test1 I will get it how should I fix this?

Comment: If you do not use `drop=FALSE` `test1` will be converted to a vector. When you later do `test1[,4]` you are trying to get the columns of the vector which is not possible since a vector doesn't have any. `test1 <- test1[order(test1[, 5]),,drop=FALSE]` (without using `as.matrix`) should preserve it as a matrix with 1 row and 5 columns and allow you to extract the 4th column later without problems.

Comment: Your welcome! I was stuck on this for quite some time too once. Realizing that `[`, `<-`, `+` etc. are actually normal functions, although with usual syntax, and that `?"["` and `?"<-"` holds good documentation for them helped a lot.

Comment: can I ask one more question? with your corrections I am not getting the error of subscript out of bound when running the program line by line. But still I have this error when I run these lines inside a function. Is there any automatic conversions inside a function which is doing it?

Comment: That seems strange to me. There should be no difference between running the command inside a function or manually. Try debugging the function by setting `options(error=browser)`, run the function to cause the error and confirm that `test1` is actually what it is supposed to be.

Comment: Oh yes I found it thank you!