# Can I control how as_tibble or as.data.frame treat one-dimensional data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, tibble

I've been running into some undesired behavior in my code when I needed to convert a matrix into a dataframe/tibble after having filtered it.
Mostly, it worked fine, but it did behave oddly when the filtered matrix had only a single row - in which case it always turned into a *column* in the generated df.
I traced my problem and [realized that my matrix was being coerced into a named vector by `` base::`[` ``](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12601739/1335174) (setting `drop=F` has solved my problem now).

Before learning about the `drop`-param I found that `as_tibble_row()` would convert a named vector fine, but in turn fails on converting my bulk of data matrices with more than one row.
I then ended up with an ugly if-else in my dplyr flow (`my_data %>% {if(is.vector(.)){as_tibble_row(.)}else{as_tibble(.)}}`) and moved on but it seems I've missed something here.

Thus **my question**:

> Is there a setting to `as_tibble` or `as.data.frame` which lets them
> know how to treat one-dimensional data and behave like `as_tibble_row`
> in that case?

(Or am I to blame for not having my data types under control, so that I didn't know whether I was passing a vector or matrix into the function?)
I've tried some things, but `as_tibble(my_data, .rows = 1)` just cuts the vector off and `as_tibble(matrix(my_data, nrow = 1, dimnames = list(NULL,names(my_data))))` seems wayy too complicated. Also, this still necessitates that I *know* I actually have to massage a vector...

Comment: Is there a reason to not convert the matrix to a tibble or data.frame first and then filter?

Comment: No strong reason, the matrix just had a bunch of columns with name `""`, which I wanted to get rid first. As I mentioned, the problem in my use-case is solved. This question is just generally, whether there exists a way to tell `as_tibble`/`as.data.frame` to handle vectors as a row

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do it using `t` to transpose your data.

```
x <- matrix(runif(16), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
colnames(x) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

x_df <- data.frame(t(x[1,])
          A         B        C         D
1 0.2875775 0.9404673 0.551435 0.6775706

library(tibble)
x_tbl <- as_tibble(t(x[1,]))
# A tibble: 1 x 4
      A     B     C     D
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0.288 0.940 0.551 0.678
```

Comment: Hey Ben, that doesn't answer my question, because it breaks when x, after filtering, has more than one row. Then I wouldn't want to transpose

Comment: I know that I can check for whether x is a vector and in that case either transpose it first or just use `as_tibble_row()`. My question is whether there is a function that works on both a vector and a matrix, but treats the vector as a row, contrary to the default behavior of those functions above where we first have to transpose